# How to delete words between specified chars?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create a method that reads from every line from a file. Next, it has to check between the pipes and determine if there are words that are more than three characters long, and are only numbers. In the file are strings organized like this:

**What's going on {noway|that's cool|1293328|why|don't know|see}**

With this sentence, the software should remove 1293328.

The resulting sentence would be:

**What's going on {noway|that's cool|don't know}**

Until now I am reading every line from the file and I made the functions that determine if the words between | | have to be deleted or not (checking a string like noway,that's cool, etc)

I don't know how to get the strings between the pipes.

Comment: Sounds like homework. What have you tried? Regex? .Split(new[]{'|')?

Comment: How should value `3.3` be handled?

Comment: Nope, it's no homework. Haven't tried regex split
I know for sure that 3.3 (float) will not be on any line :)

Answer (score 1):

You can split a string by a character using the Split method.

```
string YourStringVariable = "{noway|that's cool|1293328|why|don't know|see}";

YourStringVariable.Split('|');  //Returns an array of the strings between the brackets
```

Comment: Additionally, you can find more information here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459677/c-a-strings-split-method

Answer (score 0):

What's about:

```
string RemoveValues(string sentence, string[] values){

   foreach(string s in values){
      while(sentence.IndexOf("|" + s) != -1 && sentence.IndexOf("|" + s) != 0){
         sentence = sentence.Remove(sentence.IndexOf("|" + s), s.Lenght + 1);
      }
   }

   return sentence;
}
```

In your case:

```
string[] values = new string[3]{ "1293328", "why", "see" };
string sentence = RemoveValues("noway|that's cool|1293328|why|don't know|see", values);
//result: noway|that's cool|don't know
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        string YourStringVariable = "{noway|that's cool|1293328|why|don't know|see}";
        string[] SplitValue=g.Split('|');
        string FinalValue = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < SplitValue.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!SplitValue[i].ToString().Any(char.IsDigit))
            {
                FinalValue += SplitValue[i]+"|";    

            }

        }
```