# How to read between a specified character in a string?

Tags: c#, string

I was trying to create a list from a user input with something like this:

```
Create newlist: word1, word2, word3, etc...,
```

but how do I get those words one by one only by using commas as references going through them (in order) and placing them into an Array etc? Example:

```
        string Input = Console.ReadLine();

        if (Input.Contains("Create new list:"))
        {
            foreach (char character in Input)
            {
                if (character == ',')//when it reach a comma
                {
                    //code goes here, where I got stuck...
                }
            }
        }
```

Edit: I didn`t know the existence of "Split" my mistake... but at least it would great if you could explain me to to use it for the problem above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Split A String By Another String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245442/c-sharp-split-a-string-by-another-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#, a String's Split() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459677/c-a-strings-split-method)

Comment: You do know that you should RESEARCH first, then ask questions, do you?

Comment: Please add some code showing what you've tried already & where it fails.

Comment: Ok sorry but can you explain me how to use "split"? I didn`t even know the existence of it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this:

```
String words = "word1, word2, word3";
```

List:

```
List<string> wordsList= words.Split(',').ToList<string>();
```

Array:

```
string[] namesArray = words.Split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

@patrick Artner beat me to it, but you can just [split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) the input with the comma as the argument, or whatever you want the argument to be.

This is the example, and you will learn from the documentation.

```
    using System;

    public class Example {

    public static void Main()    {
          String value = "This is a short string.";
          Char delimiter = 's';
          String[] substrings = value.Split(delimiter);
          foreach (var substring in substrings)
             Console.WriteLine(substring);
    } 
}
```

The example displays the following output:

> ```
> Thi 
> i 
> a 
> hort 
> tring.
> ```